# Area of an ellipse. (Calculus)

Tags: calculus

This is the question extracted from a exam in my country.

The equation of the curve is $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{9}=1$

How to calculate the area of the region bounded by the curve? (9 Marks)

How to solve this by calculus? It's 9 marks question. We didn't learn that the area of an ellipse is $\pi ab$.

Comment: Did you set up the integral, as a double integral in $x,y$?  Would you like to take advantage of the symmetry of this ellipse, around its center $(0,3)$ and/or with respect to major and minor axes?

Comment: Are you allowed to distort the ellipse into a circle and use $\pi r^2$ and then rescale?

Comment: @hardmath we have not learned double integral.

Comment: Have you tried solving for $y$, then finding the area of the upper half of the ellipse?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig can you show me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Shift the axis by $(x,y)$ to $(x,y+3)$ And calculate the area.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{9}=1$$

Let $Y=y-3$

So,
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{Y^2}{9} & = 1\\
\frac{x^2}{4} & =1-\frac{Y^2}{9}\\
\frac{x^2}{4} & =\frac{1}{9}(9-Y^2)\\
x^2 & = \frac{4}{9}(9-Y^2)\\
x &  = \pm\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{9-Y^2}
\end{align*}

Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
Area & =4\int_{0}^{3}\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{9-Y^2}dY\\
& =\frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{9-Y^2}dY
\end{align*}

Let $Y=3\sin (u)$. Then $dY=3\cos (u)du$.

$$\sqrt{9-Y^2}=\sqrt{9-9\sin ^2(u)}=3\sqrt{\cos ^2(u)}$$

So, $u=\sin ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{Y}{3}\right)$.

\begin{align*}
Area & = 8\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}3 \cos (u)\sqrt{\cos ^2(u)}du\\
& = 24\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2(u)du\\
& = 24\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos (2u)+\frac{1}{2}\right)du\\
& = 12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos (2u)du+12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1du\\
& = 6\pi
\end{align*}

Comment: Your strategy looks correct, but the image is too small to check the details.  It would be better if you typed your work.

Comment: I've edited my post. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Your work looks good.  However, if I were marking it, I would want to see the step $$12\left[\frac{\sin(2u)}{2} + u\right]\bigg\vert_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$  I aligned your equations.  You can see how I did it by right-clicking on the equations, then selecting Show Math As TeX Commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot . @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2):

For a given $x$, a vertical crosses the ellipse from $y=3-\sqrt{9\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}4\right)}$ to $y=3+\sqrt{9\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}4\right)}$, i.e. over $2\sqrt{9\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}4\right)}$ units.

Hence,

$$A=6\int_{-2}^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}dx.$$

To integrate, let us use the change of variable $x=2\sin(\theta)$, and

$$A=6\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)2\cos(\theta)\,d\theta=6\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos(2\theta)+1\right)\,d\theta=\left.6\left(\frac12\sin(2\theta)+\theta\right)\right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=6\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you realise, area does not depend on location of center, only on a and b.

Taking standard equation, we get

$A = 4 \int_0^ab\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}dx$

$\Rightarrow \frac{4b}{a} \int_0^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx $

This is a standard form.. should give answer

Comment: Where did the equation come from ?

Answer (score 0):

one way to this is to parametrize the ellipse as $$x = 2\cos t, y = 3 + 3\sin t $$ and use the symmetry of the ellipse. so that the area 
$$A = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} x\, dy =  4 \int_0^{\pi/2} 2\cos t 3 \cos t \, dt = 12 \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1 + \cos 2t\right)\, dt = 6\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

A ellipse is given by $x=x_c + a\cos(t)$, $y=y_c + b\sin(t)$, i.e., $\left(\dfrac{x-x_c}a\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{y-y_c}b\right)^2 = 1$. Let $R$ be the region bounded by this ellipse. We then need
\begin{align}
A & = \int_R dxdy
\end{align}
Setting $x=x_c + a r \cos(t)$ and $y=y_c + br \sin(t)$, we see that $x,y$ vary within the ellipse as we vary $r$ from $0$ to $1$ and $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. We hence have
$$A = \int_R dx dy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 J(r,t; x,y) dr dt$$
where $J = \left \vert \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t} \end{bmatrix}\right \vert = \left \vert \begin{bmatrix} a\cos(t) & -ar\sin(t)\\ b\sin(t) & br\cos(t) \end{bmatrix}\right \vert = abr\cos^2(t) + abr\sin^2(t) = abr$. Hence, we have
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1abrdrdt = ab\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1rdrdt=ab\left(\int_0^{2\pi}dt \right)\left(\int_0^1rdr\right)=ab\cdot (2\pi)\cdot\dfrac12 = \pi ab$$